# How might I insert some JavaScript into the document of a WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using the [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control in a .NET 2.0 application, and would like to insert a bit of JavaScript code into the loaded document right before the end of the `body` element.

How might I go about accomplishing this?